# Compare JPA Entities on the database

Tags: java, jpa

I have entities, that must be compared. On Java level, this is no problem. Just write your comparator or an equals(...) method and your good. Drawback with this: You have to pull **every** entity from the DB. This is obviously not a great idea...

### Quick example:

```java
@Entity
public class Field {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id = 0L;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(unique=true)
    private String naturalFieldName = "";

    @NotBlank
    @Column(unique=true)
    private String apiFieldName = "";

    @Positive
    private float correctionFactor = 1F;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="fields", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<MeterModel> meters;

    (getter & setter omitted...)
}

@Entity
public class MeterModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id = 0L;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "Meter_Field",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_Meter") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_Field") }
    )
    private Set<Field> fields;

    (getter & setter omitted...)
}
```

As you can see `MeterModel` holds some `Fields`. The equallity check would be if other MeterModels hold the same Fields?

*NOTE: This is a simplified example. The models are more complex than this, but the main problem here are lists/sets. If I can handle those, then everything else is doable.*

Now the question: Is it possible to execute those complex equality checks on the database? Ideally, I would just get a list of IDs of equal MeterModels back.

Comment: I think you should specify the DB. This sounds like something doable, but the way will be DB specific.

Comment: It a standard Spring Boot Project with the default H2 (@see https://www.h2database.com) database. *NOTE:* The DB is **NOT** running in memory, but in file mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found the solution by myself: [Spring Data JPA - Specifications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/jpa/specifications.html)

```java
public static Specification<MeterModel> sameFields(MeterModel meterModel) {
    return (criteriaRoot, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        criteriaQuery.distinct(true);
        criteriaRoot.join("fields");

        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        for(EKMRealtimeField field: meterModel.getFields()) {
            // Make sure every field of given meter is present
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.isMember(field, criteriaRoot.get("fields")));
        }

        // Make sure size of list/set of many-to-many relation is the same as from given meter model
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(
                criteriaBuilder.size(meterModel.getFields()),
                criteriaBuilder.size(criteriaRoot.get("fields")))
        );
        
        // Finally ignore yourself
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.notEqual(criteriaRoot.get("id"), meterModel.getId()));

        return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    };
}
```